# Ordering of training dataset in weka

Tags: weka

I am new in weka and I am currently running some classification algorithms on a created dataset.

The dataset contains a class {player1,player2,player3} and its samples are sorted by player's sequence.

For example:

2,748.564,384.103,1.389,0.395,2354.950,0,1858.400,0.353,5,Player_1
1,729.143,391.086,1.479,0.378,2677.350,0,1496.900,0.333,3,Player_1
2,719.765,391.824,1.295,0.469,2659.625,0,1889.429,0.250,2,Player_1
1,726.515,388.121,1.506,0.360,2236.200,0,1431.800,0.364,4,Player_2
2,733.667,387.000,1.241,0.405,2612.450,0,2322.400,0.444,5,Player_2
1,744.343,380.000,1.516,0.366,2461.500,0,1455.050,0.417,3,Player_2
2,729.500,387.167,1.336,0.422,2150.167,0,2092.000,0.429,1,Player_3
1,734.100,398.700,1.522,0.311,2403.500,0,1497.550,0.214,3,Player_3

I figured out that if I randomly change this order,

for example:
1,734.100,398.700,1.522,0.311,2403.500,0,1497.550,0.214,3,Player_3
2,748.564,384.103,1.389,0.395,2354.950,0,1858.400,0.353,5,Player_1
1,726.515,388.121,1.506,0.360,2236.200,0,1431.800,0.364,4,Player_2
2,733.667,387.000,1.241,0.405,2612.450,0,2322.400,0.444,5,Player_2
2,742.300,394.600,1.514,0.388,2530.833,0,1454.000,1.000,1,Player_3
.....

it will usually affect the classifiers' performance. Can someone explain me why this happens?  I used NaiveBayes, RandomForest and LMT as classifiers.

Thanks in advance,
Napoleon

Comment: could you please explain the scenario more detail

Comment: Yes of course.

I have got some data from different players and I want to build a model and test it (i.e predict the class Player). Initially, the training dataset contains data sorted by the Player class. Then, I use a classifier and run a 10 CV in order to output the performance and the predictions. However, if I mix the above data in the training dataset (i.e make a dataset that isnt sorted by the class Player), the classifier's performance is affected.

Comment: The data sorted by the Player class means that the Player_1 rows will be presented as first, then the Player_2 rows follow and at last Player_3 rows. If I mix up the rows like: some of Player_1 rows then some of Player_3 rows, some of Player_1 etc it affects the prediction's accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the CV Folds parameter, the CV Random Seed or the order of the data will affect the accuracy of your classifiers.

Before training your classifiers, your data is randomly allocated to the training or testing set according to the cross-validation algorithm.  For this reason, changing the CV Folds will give more or less data for training, causing a different result.  Changing the seed will give a different allocation of data each time a different value is supplied.  Likewise, if you reorder the data and keep the seed, the same row indexes would be used for training, but the data would be in a different order, thus causing different results.